# java 8 stream convert complex map

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a map with such structure: `Map<R, Map<S, Map<D, K>>>` and I need to convert it to `Map<R, Map<D, Map<S, K>>>` any idea how to implement it with streams?
In my case it looks like: `Map<Long, Map<String, Map<Long, Double>>>`

And the data:

```
{1->{"m"->{2->3.0},{3->1.0},{4->2.0}}}
{1->{"n"->{2->1.0},{3->2.2},{5->3.2}}}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Depends 100% on your desired mapping. And it would probably be helpful seeing an example, not just cryptic `R S D K`

Comment: This is not always possible. What if there is similar D keys associated to a different S key ?

Comment: Looking at your input data, it's not possible to represent that using the map structure `Map<R, Map<S, Map<D, K>>>` because you have two values for the same R key (1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, it appears that the outer map level is not involved in the transformation, so let's forget about it for the time being. You have `Map<S,Map<D,K>>` and you want to turn it into `Map<D,Map<S,K>>`. You could try the following:

```
Map<S,Map<D,K>> src = ...;
Map<D,Map<S,K>> dest = src.entrySet().stream() // Stream<Map.Entry<S,Map<D,K>>>
    .flatMap(eO -> {
        final S curS = eO.getKey();
        return eO.getValue().entrySet().stream() // Stream<Map.Entry<D,K>>
            .map(eI -> new Object[] { curS, eI.getKey(), eI.getValue() });
            // Stream<Object[]{S,D,K}> for this S
    }) // Stream<Object[]{S,D,K}> for all S
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            arr -> (D)arr[1], // What to group by in the outer level
            Collectors.toMap( // What to do with the inner level values for each D
                arr -> (S)arr[0], // Keys for the inner map
                arr -> (K)arr[2]  // Values for the inner map
    )));
```

Of course, the code might seem a bit awkward due to the use of casts, but it avoids the need for a type-safe 3-tuple class. Take a deep look at the code because I'm away from any Java compiler, but I *think* it ought to do what you want it to do.